# How to declare virtual interface with params in the top module (in the testbench)?

Tags: interface, system-verilog

I have the following parameterised interface:

```
interface axi_interface #(parameter DATA_SIZE = 0)
  (input bit ACLK, input bit ARESETn);
   //write address channel signals
   logic [3:0]  AWID; //
   logic [31:0] AWADDR;
   .....
   .....
endinterface
```

I try to declare this interface as a virtual interface in the top module (in the testbench):

```
module girobo2_tb_top;
   .....
   .....
   axi_interface #(.DATA_SIZE(63)) axi_vif(tb_axi_clk, axi_arstn);
   .....
   .....
endmodule
```

But, I got the following error when I run the simulation:

```
# ** Error: (vsim-7065) ../sv/girobo2_tb_top.sv(245): Illegal assignment to type 'virtual axi_interface' from type 'interface axi_interface #(.DATA_SIZE(63))': Vir. 'axi_interface' interface must be assigned a matching interface or virtual interface.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to assign a parameterised interface to a virtual interface, you need to parameterise the virtual interface, too, eg:

```
virtual axi_interface #(.DATA_SIZE(63)) vif;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3KvL

You might like to watch this [video tutorial](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/video_gallery/#anchor52) on my company's website, which I have just come across. You'll see one the other regular contributors here is acknowledged.